# Can't restart Fluent Bit service

Tags: fluent-bit

I am using the "td-agent-bit" service to collect the logs of my app1 node application into a file named "file.log". In my "td-agent-bit.conf" file I left the [SERVICE] section unchanged, but I changed the [INPUT] and [OUTPUT] sections:

```
...
[INPUT]
    Name forward
    Listen localhost
    Port 24224

[OUTPUT]
    Name        file
    Match       *
    Path        /etc/td-agent-bit/file.log
    Format      json
```

The "file.log" exists and has all the permissions because I launched the command

```
sudo chmod 777 file.log
```

But when I do

```
sudo service td-agent-bit restart
```

I get the following error:

```
× td-agent-bit.service - TD Agent Bit
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/td-agent-bit.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2024-02-07 13:16:53 UTC; 45min ago
       Docs: https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/
    Process: 2541 ExecStart=/opt/td-agent-bit/bin/td-agent-bit -c //etc/td-agent-bit/td-agent-bit.conf (code=exited, status=255/EXCEPTION)
   Main PID: 2541 (code=exited, status=255/EXCEPTION)
        CPU: 23ms

Feb 07 13:16:53 fluent-bit-d-machine systemd[1]: td-agent-bit.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Feb 07 13:16:53 fluent-bit-d-machine systemd[1]: Stopped TD Agent Bit.
Feb 07 13:16:53 fluent-bit-d-machine systemd[1]: td-agent-bit.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Feb 07 13:16:53 fluent-bit-d-machine systemd[1]: td-agent-bit.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 07 13:16:53 fluent-bit-d-machine systemd[1]: Failed to start TD Agent Bit.
```

Answer (score 0):

I just removed

```
Format      json
```

from the "td-agent-bit.conf" file and it has restarted properly.